# Move Back Button to the right UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I need to move the stock back button over to the right just a few pixels as its so far to the left that when the iPad is in certain cases you cannot see the button at all.

What i've tried:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setImageInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0, 0)];
[self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setImageInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0, 0)];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar.backItem.backBarButtonItem setImageInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0, 0)];
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What is "self" above? A view controller?

Back buttons are provided by the previous VC on the stack, so you might try it on whatever view controller is pushing your next VC.

Comment: Self is the base view controller from which all of the other VC's in the app inherit from.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, that solution isn't working in the latest versions of iOS (11+). What i made to move the back button image was an extension:

```
extension UIImage {
  func withInsets(_ insets: UIEdgeInsets) -> UIImage? {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(
      CGSize(width: size.width + insets.left + insets.right,
             height: size.height + insets.top + insets.bottom),
      false,
      self.scale)
    let origin = CGPoint(x: insets.left, y: insets.top)
    self.draw(at: origin)
    let imageWithInsets = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return imageWithInsets
  }
}
```

Then, you can call your implementation like:

`UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "icon-back")?.withInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10.0, bottom: 0, right: 0 ))`